# How can I resolve "Error: Failed to decode resource from state"?

Tags: terraform-provider-aws

I've got some old terraform that I've inherited. I'm trying do something with an old project that I haven't touched before - and didn't have a committed `.terraform.lock.hcl` file. Relevant bits look like:

```
resource "aws_vpc_peering_connection" "example" {
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.vpc.id
  peer_vpc_id = var.example-vpc-id
  auto_accept = true
}
```

When I try to run `plan` for an unrelated change (elasticache engine upgrade, if it matters), I get this error:

> Error: Failed to decode resource from state
>
> Error decoding "aws_vpc_peering_connection.example" from previous state: unsupported attribute "allow_classic_link_to_remote_vpc"

I've seen that the `allow_classic_link_to_remote_vpc` is an old field that was removed([1](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#500-may-25-2023))([2](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/guides/version-5-upgrade)) in 5.0.0 of the aws provider. I don't have that in the hcl here, but it must somehow be in state?

`terraform --version` shows:

```
Terraform v1.3.9
on darwin_arm64
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws v5.21.0
...
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Maybe a dumb question on my side, but have you tried to use an older AWS provider version where the attribute exists? Then, you could try to run a plan/apply & remove that attribute from the state. Also, another idea: you could try some state surgery (`terraform state rm <resource-id>`) to remove the resource from the state & re-add it with the updated configuration (the invalid attribute removed). Be careful removing things from state, if you choose that route.